Raising errors from a generator function immediately
I have a python class that is a wrapper around a datafile containing a number of variables and attributes. Some of these variables may have also have attributes associated with them, and I want to be able to iterate over these attributes using a generator. I want to be able to raise an Exception if a specified variable does not exist in the file, and yield the attributes if it does exist in the file. The problem, however, is that I would prefer to be able to raise the exception immediately, but because generator functions in Python are evaluated lazily, the exception only gets thrown when the generator is first evaluated. This essentially boils down to the following:
class file:
    
    def __init__(self, varlist: List[str], attrlist: Dict[str, Any]):
        self.varlist = varlist
        self.attrlist = attrlist

    def loadvar(self, varname: str):
        ...

    def attrs(self, varname: str = None):
        if varname:
            if varname not in self.varlist:
                raise RuntimeError(f"{varname} is not a valid variable name")
            yield from self.loadvar(varname).attrs()
        yield from self.attrlist.keys()

datafile = file(['a', 'b','c'], {'d':1, 'e':2, 'f':3})
list(datafile.attrs('non-existent')) # <-- raises exception; good
attr = datafile.attrs('non-existent')) # <-- does not raise exception; bad
list(attr)  # <-- does raise exception


This is just a silly snippet example, so the logical doesn't necessarily make sense. Is it at all possible to raise an exception when the generator function is called, rather than evaluated?

doing two things
You say you want to

validate, and then
generate

That sounds like it deserves two methods.
Break out a _private helper.
    def attrs(self, varname: str | None = None):
        if varname and varname not in self.varlist:
            raise RuntimeError(f"{varname} is not a valid variable name")
        return self._attrs1(varname)

    def _attrs1(self, varname: str | None):
        if varname:
            yield from self.loadvar(varname).attrs()

        yield from self.attrlist.keys()

Notice that attr() is not itself a generator,
but it returns a lazy generator.
So it is evaluated at once, and then caller
is hanging onto a generator which it can
call next() on at its leisure.
PEP 8
Please prefer to write
class File:
    
    def __init__(self, varlist: list[str], attrs: dict[str, Any]):

That is, capital class name, and lowercase list + dict
in modern annotations.
Also, not sure why self is missing from your method signatures.
Perhaps you meant to talk about functions
(without the four-space indent) and the class statement
somehow was accidentally pasted in there?

Thanks for the answer couple of things: I wrote this on SO rather than copy paste, which is why I forgot the 'self'. I'm using list and dict from typing, hence the uppercase. I also take the controversial view that PEP8 is soft guidelines, not hard. I prefer lowercase classnames. Not trying to argue, just how I work.

Linking PEP 8's "Naming Conventions" but misspelling PEP 8's name ... ts ts ts...
